# How to read parquet file compressed by .gz in databricks?

Tags: python, databricks, parquet, azure-blob-storage, gunzip

My file is stored on an Azure's blob storage and it looks like `1627937153-1627937153-ab_test-20210604-0-0.parquet.gz`. How can I read the data from this file in databricks using Python without downloading this file into databricks environment? I have multiple files of the same format in the same folder. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Guess already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63372269)??

Answer (score 0):

1. 

You may try

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_parquet("myFile.parquet.gzip")
display(df)
```

as referred in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63372269) by @bala
(or)

2.
From [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729820/how-to-read-parquet-file-from-azure-python-function-blob-input-binding)

```
 import io
df = pd.read_parquet(blob_to_read, engine='pyarrow')
display(df)
```

(Or)
3.

Try using gzip file to read from a zip file

```
import gzip
file = gzip.open("filename.parquet.gz", "rb")
df = file.read()
display(df)
```

4. 

You can also this article on [zip-files-python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/zip-files-python.html) taken from [zip-files-python-notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/zip-files.html#zip-files-python-notebook)  which shows how to unzip files which has these steps  as below :

1.retrieve file

2.Unzip file

3.Move file to DBFS

And finally load file into data frame using

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header","true").load("dbfs:/tmp/LoanStats3a. parquet ")
display(df)
```

5. 

If in case you use azure data lake gen2 ,check this
pyarrowfs-adlgen2 is an implementation of a pyarrow filesystem for Azure Data Lake Gen2. See >  [Use pyarrow with Azure Data Lake gen2](https://github.com/kaaveland/pyarrowfs-adlgen2)  .It allows you to use pyarrow and pandas to read parquet datasets directly from Azure without the need to copy files to local storage first.